# Cartesian Product: Terence Tao, Analysis 1 (Exercise 3.5.1)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Exercise 3.5.1.** Suppose we define the ordered pair $(x, y)$ for any objects $x$ and $y$ by the formula
$$
(x, y) := \bigl\{\{x\}, \{x, y\}\bigr\} 
$$
(thus using several applications of
Axiom 3.3). Thus for instance,
$(1, 2)$ is the set $\{\{1\}, \{1, 2\}\}$,
$(2, 1)$ is the set $\{\{2\}, \{2, 1\}\}$, and
$(1, 1)$ is the set $\{\{1\}\}$.
Show that such a definition indeed obeys the property (3.5), and also whenever $X$ and $Y$ are sets, the Cartesian product $X \times Y$ is also a set. Thus this definition can be validly used as a definition of an ordered pair. For an additional challenge, show that the alternate definition
$$
(x, y) := \bigl\{x, \{x, y\}\bigr\} 
$$
also verifies (3.5) and is thus also an acceptable definition of ordered pair. (For this latter task one needs the axiom
of regularity, and in particular Exercise 3.2.2.)

**I am aware of the different proofs presented on stack exchange, but I cannot follow them. Hence, I present my own proof in order to receive feedback with regards to its soundness:**

$\forall a \in X,\, \exists \{a\}$,
(from the singleton set axiom).

$\forall b \in Y,\, \exists \{b\}$,
(from the singleton set axiom).

This implies, since {a} is an object $\forall a \in X$, and since $\{b\}$ is an object  $\forall a \in X$, there exists $\{a,b\}$ for each $a \in X$ and for each $b \in Y$ (from the singleton and pair set axiom.)

Also, for all $a$ belonging to $X$ there exists a set
$$
M := \Bigl\{ \bigl\{ \{m\}, \{g, h\} \bigr\} 
\mid a \in X,\, g \in X,\, h \in Y \Bigr\}. 
$$
Each element of this set is of the form
$\bigl\{\{m\}, \{g,h\}\bigr\}$,
where $m \in X,\, g \in X,\, h \in Y$. Such an element is a valid construction given the "'singleton/pair' set axiom".

Now, given the set $M$, we may invoke axiom of specification, in order to construct set
$$
R := \Bigl\{ \bigl\{ \{m\}, \{g, h\} \bigr\} 
\mid m \in X,\, g \in X,\, h \in Y,\, \text{and}\, m=g \Bigr\}.
$$

Thus completing the proof.

Correct? Incorrect? Please help.

Comment: Please use MathJax

Comment: How do I go about using it? Installing it?

Comment: You have shown that such a set exists, but you haven't shown the most important part: that this definition accords with our usual understanding of what an ordered pair is. You have to show that if $(a,b)=(c,d)$ then $a=c$ and $b=d$.

Comment: As for MathJax, you don't have to install anything -- it's built into the web page. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a tutorial. Basically, you enclose equations in dollar signs to render them in MathJax; so \$x=y\$ comes out as $x=y$. Sets are a bit awkward, because the curly brackets { and } are MathJax delimiters, so to get them to display properly you have to precede them with a backslash: \$\{x\}\$ comes out as $\{x\}$.

Comment: I went ahead and edited to put in MathJax/LaTeX formatting. Click `Edit` to have a look at source code (modify if I've inadvertently changed something).

Comment: @SammyBlack grateful!

Comment: I'm not sure how your pair axiom is stated, but generally, it requires $a, b$ to exist, not $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$. Also, all you have done is argued for the existence of certain sets. The problem also specifies proving that $\{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$ acts like an ordered pair. In particular, that $\{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\} = \{\{x\}, \{x,y\}\}$ if and only if $x = a$ and $y = b$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: Yeah, I have no problem with that part of the question. Just the one outlined above. I just think that I am running into something similar to the Russell's Paradox....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know exactly how Terence Tao states his axioms, but the general form of this I am familiar with is

- Axiom of pairs: $\forall a \forall b \exists S \forall x (x \in S \iff x = a\vee x = b)$.

S is commonly denoted by $\{a, b\}$ or $\{b, a\}$.

From this, you prove the existences of singletons $\forall a, \{a\} = \{a,a\}$, and $\forall a\forall b\exists\{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\}$, which we denote by $(a,b)$.

Next is a construction axiom:

- If $T(x)$ is some construction based on $x$, then $$\forall A\exists B\forall y(y \in B \iff \exists x(x\in A \wedge y = T(x))).$$

I.e., for any set $A$, there is a set $\{T(x) \mid x \in A\}$.

Using this axiom, for all $x \in X, \exists S_x = \{(x,y) \mid y \in Y\}$.

And using it again, there is a set $\mathcal C = \{S_x \mid x \in X\}$.

Finally, using the axiom of union, $X \times Y = \bigcup \mathcal C$.